# IEEE Transaction on Circuits and Systems Review Process

Tags: peer-review, ieee

I submitted a journal paper to IEEE Transaction on Circuits and Systems for Video Technology on June 12th. Today, after 40 days, I checked its status and it went from "In Peer Review" to "Awaiting Recommendation". What does "Awaiting Recommendation" mean? Also, Considering that it usually takes the review process about 100 days to finish, should I expect the manuscript to be rejected?

Thanks

Comment: Having moved from "In Peer Review" to "Awaiting Recommendation," I'd guess that your manuscript is awaiting a recommendation from the editor. Regarding, "100 days to finish," I don't know where you got that figure nor how you think that it suggests rejection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the reviewers already submitted their scores and now the paper is with the associate editor who will make a recommendation to the Editor-in-Chief.

The next step will be "awaiting final decision" which will be made by the Editor-in-Chief.

It will take probably a week or less to get a decision now based on my experience.

At this point, the paper could get accepted or rejected. You cannot infer anything from this status.

I recently submitted a TCAS journal paper and went through this process.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please share how long did the peer review take for your paper?

Comment: Around 40 days for my paper from submission to final decision. Peer review took around 1 month.